# Mathjax does not render on Chrome after deployment to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, mathjax

I am creating a website on Google App Engine and have a problem that Mathjax dose not work on Chrome.

It has no problem when testing the website on my local machines, but after I publish to GAE, Mathjax stop working only for Chrome.

[Here is the website](http://trivialgadgetlab.appspot.com/childsplayexperiment/zerocompression)

I put Mathjax CDN link and configuration at the bottom of body tag, it looks like

```
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js" type="text/javascript">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AmsMath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
            processEscapes: true,
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
    });
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML""></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/childsplayexp.js"></script>


</body>
```

I have tried moving it to different places but nothing has changed. I have no clue now.

Sorry for not informative, but I don't know myself what has happened at all, please feel free to post a guess, it sure is valuable for me.

Comment: Have you looked in the chrome console -- [blocked] The page at https://trivialgadgetlab.appspot.com/childsplayexperiment/zerocompression ran insecure content from http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js.  Thats your answer.

Comment: If you access it in chrome via http://trivialgadgetlab.appspot.com/childsplayexperiment/zerocompression it renders the page correctly.  Your base for the javascript needs to be https or http matching the url you retrieved it from.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your page.

- The main problem: As the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#secure-access-to-the-cdn) says, https is not supported at `cdn.mathjax.org`, but you can use the equally stable https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js

**UPDATE this has [changed in 2014](http://www.mathjax.org/changes-to-the-mathjax-cdn/). SSL now works on cdn.mathjax.org and the rackcdn address has been retired.**

**UPDATE (2017). The copy at `cdn.mathjax.org` will be retired. Check [mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/) for migration tips.**

- A lesser problem is that script for the MathJax linline configuration block has the wrong type -- it should be `text/x-mathjax-config`. Again, see [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options) for more detail.